# CSS Filters break 3D transforms

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms, css-filters

I was experimenting with CSS transforms when I found that filters flatten the transforms, just like `transform-style: flat`.

```js
var toggleFilter = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("cube")
  if (div.className == "cube") {
    div.className = "cube filter"
  } else {
    div.className = "cube"
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  transform-style: preserve-3d
}
div.cube {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  border: solid 2px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.face1 {
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px) translateX(50px);
  border: solid 2px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.face2 {
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px) translateX(50px);
  border: solid 2px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.perspective {
  perspective: 900px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 50px;
}
.filter {
  filter: opacity(1);
  -webkit-filter: opacity(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="perspective">
  <div id="cube" class="cube">
    <div class="face1"></div>
    <div class="face2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="toggleFilter()">Toggle .filter</button>
```

[Here's a fiddle demonstrating this.](https://jsfiddle.net/jmg8mhdp/21/)
 I couldn't find any information on this anywhere, so I would like to know if there is a workaround for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per [W3C Transforms Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-style-property):

> The following CSS property values **require the user agent to create a flattened representation of the descendant elements** before they can be applied, and therefore **override the behavior of transform-style: preserve-3d**:
>
> `overflow`: any value other than visible.
>
> **`filter`: any value other than none.**
>
> `clip`: any value other than auto.
>
> `clip-path`: any value other than none.
>
> `isolation`: used value of isolate.
>
> `mask-image`: any value other than none.
>
> `mask-box-image-source`: any value other than none.
>
> `mix-blend-mode`: any value other than normal.
>
> The computed value of transform-style is not affected.

This is the reason why the 3D transforms are broken and the layers are flattened when you toggle on the filters. The one workaround that I know for this situation is **creating the entire cube using sibling elements** and apply the `filter` on the sibling elements directly instead of applying on the parent.

```js
var toggleFilter = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("cube")
  if (div.className == "cube") {
    div.className = "cube filter"
  } else {
    div.className = "cube"
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  transform-style: preserve-3d
}
div.cube {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
}
div.face0 {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: blue;
  border: solid 2px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.face1 {
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px) translateX(50px);
  border: solid 2px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.face2 {
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px) translateX(50px);
  border: solid 2px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.perspective {
  perspective: 900px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 50px;
}
.filter .face0,
.filter .face1,
.filter .face2 {
  filter: opacity(25%);
  -webkit-filter: opacity(25%);
}
```

```html
<div class="perspective">
  <div id="cube" class="cube">
    <div class="face0"></div>
    <div class="face1"></div>
    <div class="face2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="toggleFilter()">Toggle .Filter</button>
```

Comment: can this also be achieved with `backdrop-filter`s somehow?