# CSS perspective, filter combination not working in latest chromium

Tags: css, chromium, css-transforms, css-filters

when i add perspective rotation and filter:blur().

Firefox (44.0.2), Chrome (48.0.2564.116 (64-bit) ), Safari (9.0.3) have no Problem with this. 
My Chromium Version is 51.0.2666.0 (64-bit) - Canary Build: 378711, from March the 2nd 2016. I tried several versions of Chromium, no version seems to work.

My setup: MacOs 10.11.3, MacBook with Retina Display.

I made a pen including a screenshot, how it should look like.
Can you reproduce this error? Do you see a shadow on the third box?

```css
.wrap {
  perspective: 600px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.with--perspective:before {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
}

.with--blur:before {
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
}

.with--changedperspective:before {
  transform: rotateX(85deg);
}



/*

 some stuff for this example
*/

.find-the-error {
  display: flex;
  padding: 50px;
}

.wrap{
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 240px;
  background: #eaeaea;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  flex-basis: 25%;
}  

.wrap:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2rem;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 2em;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.screenshot {
  text-align: center;
  
  img {
    max-width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="find-the-error">
<div class="wrap with--perspective">
  no blur <br>
  perspective works
</div>

<div class="wrap with--blur">
  no perspective <br>
  blur works
</div>

<div class="wrap with--blur with--perspective">
  adding both <br>
  perspective seems to work but blur hides all (only visible in devtools)
</div>

<div class="wrap with--blur with--changedperspective">
  adding a rotation of 85deg<br>
  shows both, blur and perspective, but blur looks strange
</div>
</div>

<div class="screenshot">
  <img width="100" height="103" title="" alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />

</div>
```

Comment: I didn't fully understand what you mean by *blur hides all* or *blur looks strange* but have a look at this answer and see if it helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555106/css-filters-break-3d-transforms/34556908#34556908

Comment: you need to look at the source, when i add filter: blur(); to the perspective rotated box. the box isnt visible. See the 
[codepen](http://codepen.io/gezeichnet/pen/XdbRxK?editors=1100) for this

Comment: Isn't that the same as the snippet you've included in question? Anyway, I don't see any problems so I'll leave to others who can see it.