# Add box-shadow to transformed div

Tags: html, css

I am working on making a 3D looking book using only CSS. I am at the final step, which is to add `box-shadow` to it.

How do I add `box-shadow:10px 10px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)` to it? I presume I need to adjust the div setup.

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tpw85kLb/) for visuals.

```css
.book-image-wrap {
  margin: 25px auto;
  height: 346px;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  -moz-perspective: 1200px;
  perspective: 1200px;
}

.book-image {
  background: #000;
  height: 346px;
  width: 230px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 16px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
  border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  -moz-perspective: 1200px;
  perspective: 1200px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(30deg);
  transform: rotateY(30deg);
}

.book-image-cover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 230px;
  max-width: 230px;
  max-height: 346px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0;
  transform-origin: 0;
}

.book-image-cover:after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  box-shadow: 1px 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 3px;
}

.book-image-spine {
  background: darkred;
  width: 40px;
  height: 344px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0;
  transform-origin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-image-wrap" style="width:250px;height:400px;">
  <div class="book-image" style="width:250px;height:400px;">
    <div class="book-image-cover" style="background:url(https://d202m5krfqbpi5.cloudfront.net/books/1347457482l/13248057.jpg);max-width:250px;max-height:400px;width:250px;"></div>
    <div class="book-image-spine" style="width:40px;height:400px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I **really** like how it's render, great job! +1 My guess would be to wrap the divs in a way where the box-shadow will work.

Comment: Pretty sure that just adding it to book-image would give a decent enough result

Comment: Place it on `.book-image` .... https://jsfiddle.net/tpw85kLb/1/

Comment: @LinkinTED The box-shadow needs to be on the left side, not right.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mj60daz5/ just use negative px settings to get it on the left side.

Comment: @GuillaumeRoche-Bayard But now the shadow is covering the spine of the book. This was my initial issue with this!

Comment: @HenrikPetterson, check out my answer, is that what you want?

Comment: Is this close to what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/41zvqf3u/

Comment: @ovokuro Yes! Beside the *white* areas that appeared on the book's spine.

Comment: I believe you could use ::before to create pseudo elements and use box shadow on them, but i couldn't manage to get it done for now ..

Comment: You can remove the `right` property and increase the `blur` --https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/uuoq5dhs/

Comment: @ovokuro Nearly there. Is there no way to not make the shadow overlap the spine? I made the spine color `white` and you can see clearly how it overlaps: https://jsfiddle.net/uuoq5dhs/1/

Comment: I don't see an overlap on Chrome 61. What browser are you using?

Comment: @ovokuro It overlaps on Firefox and Safari. Works on Chrome surprisingly.

Comment: @ovokuro Any luck?

Comment: Sorry, I'm stumped. I can't find a way to adjust the stacking order in firefox...

Answer (score 0):

you could add `filter:drop-shadow(-10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8));` to your `.book-image-wrap`

see here: https://jsfiddle.net/tpw85kLb/3/

and adjust the px values to your needs

Comment: Thanks but this seems to mess up the setup. Try to add and remove the drop-shadow and you will see what I mean. **Note:** Please test this with Firefox. I looks okay in Chrome!

Comment: oh well, i checked in chrome initially... going to try a little bit more

Comment: well, i did find the problem, but no real solution yet: it seems the filter overrides the preserve-3d, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555106/css-filters-break-3d-transforms

Answer (score 0):

As @Guillaume Roche-Bayard suggested, just add the box-shadow property to **.book-image**. In addition I have added the same property to .book-image-cover also.

```css
.book-image-wrap {
  margin: 25px auto;
  height: 346px;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  -moz-perspective: 1200px;
  perspective: 1200px;
}

.book-image {
  background: #000;
  height: 346px;
  width: 230px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 16px;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow:-25px 10px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
  border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  -moz-perspective: 1200px;
  perspective: 1200px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(30deg);
  transform: rotateY(30deg);
}

.book-image-cover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow:-25px 10px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  width: 230px;
  max-width: 230px;
  max-height: 346px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0;
  transform-origin: 0;
}

.book-image-cover:after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  box-shadow: 1px 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 3px;
}

.book-image-spine {
  background: darkred;
  width: 40px;
  height: 344px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0;
  transform-origin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-image-wrap" style="width:250px;height:400px;">
  <div class="book-image" style="width:250px;height:400px;">
    <div class="book-image-cover" style="background:url(https://d202m5krfqbpi5.cloudfront.net/books/1347457482l/13248057.jpg);max-width:250px;max-height:400px;width:250px;"></div>
    <div class="book-image-spine" style="width:40px;height:400px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is incorrect. As I noted to Guillaume in the comments, I want the shadow to be dropped on the **left** side, not right.

Comment: Hope this helps now. Changed a bit, from 10px to -25px